# How to deal with viewholder and flow in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-livedata, android-viewholder, kotlin-stateflow

I would like to use my variable `flow` to save `integer` and keep him. Then every viewholder in recyclerview observe flow and react if it is clicked. For example:

I have `cardView` when I click on that I use method

```
statusButtons.toggleVisibility(!statusButtons.isVisible)
```

.. then my element expose like in the swipe mode, if I click on another element, previous element should (swipe back) or just `toggleVisisbility` to `isNotVisible` in my case.

Now, if I click on my element everytime I trigger only this one element so I can't hide others and make actions on this.

For now I started like that:

```
    val _stateFlow = MutableStateFlow(-1)
    val stateFlow = _stateFlow.asStateFlow()


cardView.onClickListener {

_stateFlow.value = absoluteAdapterPosition
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hej Chrisu,

the stateFlow should be part of your `Adapter` and when you build a new `ViewHolder` you inject the variable into the `ViewHolder`. With this the stateFlow is only created once and all holders can observe it.

Something like this:

```
Adapter{
    val stateFlow = MutableStateFlow(-1)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder = 
    ViewHolder(stateFlow)
}


ViewHolder(val stateFlow: MutableStateFlow){

    init{
      cardView.onClickListener {
        _stateFlow.value = absoluteAdapterPosition
      }
    }
}
```